# MongoDB thinks it's running a replica?

Tags: mongodb

I'm running MongoDB (version 2.4) behind a Django application served by Apache.

In the past few days, I'm seeing the following error come up many times an hour in the Apache logs, on all sorts of different requests:

```
AutoReconnect: not master and slaveOk=false
```

I did not explicitly create a replica, and to the best of my knowledge am not running one. rs.status() says that we are not running with --replset.

Mongo is run with:

```
'mongod --dbpath /srv/db/mongodb/ --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend --auth'
```

There is one mongod process running on the server.

What's going on here?

---

Edit - 
Here's the tail end of the stack trace, as requested.

```
File "/var/www/sefaria_dev/sefaria/texts.py", line 916, in parse_ref
  shorthand = db.index.find_one({"maps": {"$elemMatch": {"from": pRef["book"]}}})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 604, in find_one
  for result in self.find(spec_or_id, *args, **kwargs).limit(-1):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 904, in next
  if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 848, in _refresh
  self.__uuid_subtype))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 800, in __send_message
  self.__uuid_subtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 98, in _unpack_response
  raise AutoReconnect(error_object["$err"])
AutoReconnect: not master and slaveOk=false
```

---

rs.status() returns:

```
{
   "ok" : 0,
   "errmsg" : "not running with --replSet"
}
```

rs.conf() returns null.

I haven't seen an indication of error in the mongodb.log that corresponds to one of the apache.log errors.

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is a community for **software developers**. Your question, however, is about **administration and configuration** of mongodb, not about developing software based on it. For that reason I voted to move it to https://dba.stackexchange.com. Please always try to post on the stackexchange site where your question fits best.

Comment: Once it's migrated, could you post excerpts from the logs around when the messages show up? Also please post the output of `rs.status()` and `rs.conf()` just so there's no ambiguity. Is there anything else unusual going on, like interruptions in connectivity or the mongod restarting?

Comment: Can you please cut/paste the error from the log file exactly?  I have searched the source code -- is it an error or an assert?

Comment: Here's a stack trace.

Comment: The output of `rs.conf()` and `rs.status()` are missing. And please add the according lines from `mongod.log`, too.